How to prevent displaying DebuggingOverlay in Layout Inspector in Android Studio for react native app?
When running my react native app in Layout Inspector there are DebuggingOverlay components shown instead of Jetpack components. How can I fix it?

I have my expo project prebuilt, and there is android folder.
I run the command npm run start, and then run the project in Android Studio.
I have already set override fun getUseDeveloperSupport(): Boolean = false in MainApplication.kt and removed <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" android:exported="false" /> in AndroidManifest.xml, but it didn't help.
Versions:

"react-native": "0.74.5"
"expo": "~51.0.3"

